# github.com is not responding on my internet but is working when I turn on the proxy server

Tags: github, proxy

github.com is not responding on my internet but is working when i turn  on the proxy server.
It is showing this when connected to my internet-

***This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://github.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID*
**

I tried DNS server settings and all but still the same error continues please help.